# Constructing a complex number geometrically, without putting it in standard form.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Is there any way to construct geometrically a number like $1/(3+5i)$ without putting it in the standard form (i.e. like $a+bi$)? How to do it? I want the localization of the number, without changing the way it is expressed.

Comment: Are you allowed to compute and manipulate the magnitude?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli: Yes, but is there a way to do it without doing this? I am very, very confused about this.

Comment: Reflect it across the $x$ axis. Find the magnitude by using stereographic projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complex multiplicative inversion ($z\mapsto\frac1z$) can be expressed as a reflection in the real axis ($z\mapsto\bar z$) combined with a circle inversion in the unit circle ($z\mapsto\frac1{\bar z}$). The order doesn't matter. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Circle_inversion) for instructions on how to construct an inversion.